# One of the best person I got to work with

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to write a recommendation. How could I improve the following sentence which sounds too informal and it also sounds like it is in the past whereas I am still working with this person:

`He is one of the best person I got to work with`

Comment: "He was fantastic to work with. One of the best."  

This, however, seems more like a writing question than an english language question.

Comment: There are a million ways. Which one to pick is subjective and argumentative. However, the real problem with your sentence is not that it's informal. The problem is that it is not English. So this amounts to proofreading, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is one of the best people that I have worked with.